# is not a valid Cucumber report! String length (20054016) exceeds the maximum length (20000000)

Tags: jenkins, jackson, cucumber, karate

I am using the karate framework for automation testing with cucumber-reporting plugin version 5.3.1. after running the automation i am getting the error.

Could you please help me increase this max string length limit

I want that if possible it creates the reports and increase this size limit. The way to override this size limit.

Error is: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZObz.png)

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamConstraintsException: String length (20051119) exceeds the maximum length (20000000)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamReadConstraints.validateStringLength(StreamReadConstraints.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.ReadConstrainedTextBuffer.validateStringLength(ReadConstrainedTextBuffer.java:27)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.finishCurrentSegment(TextBuffer.java:939)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._finishString2(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2240)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._finishString(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2206)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.getText(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:323)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer._deserializeContainerNoRecursion(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:572)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:100)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:25)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4801)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.json.deserializers.CucumberJsonDeserializer.deserialize(CucumberJsonDeserializer.java:25)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.json.deserializers.EmbeddingDeserializer.deserialize(EmbeddingDeserializer.java:22)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3785)
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseForFeature(ReportParser.java:90)
... 15 more

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin/issues/449